# DestroySession function preventing logging out of facebook

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-php-sdk, logout

I'm trying to rework the logout system of my Zend site to also log users out of facebook, in compliance with the facebook app policy, but I'm not having any luck. Here's the code in my logout action to check if the user is logged into facebook and log them out if so.

```
require_once(BASE_PATH . "/library/facebook-php/src/facebook.php");
    $facebook = new Facebook( array('appId'=>'app id', 
                        'secret'=>'secret') );
    $fbid = $facebook->getUser();
    if($fbid){
        $facebook->destroySession();
        $this->_redirect( $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>'http://completeset.us/organizer/index') ) );
    }
```

With the destroySession in there, I am logged out of my site, but not out of facebook for some reason. If I take it out, I am logged out of both sites, but since the session is still there I am immediately logged back into my site because it detects that session and is able to match it to my account. How can I both log the user out of facebook and destroy the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that facebook needed the session to be able to log the user out or something. Redirecting to the logout url in my logout action and then deleting the session afterward in my callback url instead of trying to delete it first worked perfectly.